# Creating pairs from two columns using each id only once

Tags: r, data.table

I have a list of pairs with two ids : (ida, idb).
I want to construct from this list, a list of "unique pairs" in the sense that each id (ida and idb) is only used once.

It is possible that some elements of ida don't match any element of idb. But all the elements of idb have to be preserved (Like row 6 and 6 in the example below).

This implies that number of final pairs of the solution should be equal to the number of unique element of idb.

Multiple solutions are sometimes possible, I just need one of them.

```
dt1 = data.table(ida = c(7,7,8,8,15,16,17,18,19,19,20), idb = c(2,1,2,1,4,5,5,6,7,8,8))
ida idb
1:   7   2
2:   7   1
3:   8   2
4:   8   1
5:  15   4
6:  16   5
7:  17   5
8:  18   6
9:  19   7
10:  19   8
11:  20   8
```

Yields:

```
 ida idb
1:   7   2
2:   8   1
3:  15   4
4:  16   5
5:  18   6
6:  19   7
7:  20   8
```

Or:

```
ida idb
1:   7   1
2:   8   2
3:  15   4
4:  17   5
5:  18   6
6:  19   7
7:  20   8
```

Where we have nrow(result) == length(unique(dt1$idb)). And of course length(unique(result$ida)) == length(unique(result$idb)).

Note: In the first solution the element 17 has been removed from ida. This is an expected behavior: it is not possible to link 16 and 17 to 5 at the same time since 5 has to be unique.

Comment: Can this be also `7 1` and `8 2`

Comment: Try `dt1[,lapply(.SD, unique)]`

Comment: Sorry I edited the topic with a special case. lapply(.SD, unique) doesn't work because it recycles the column to fill the missing values. I'd like the id with no match to be removed from the table.

Comment: Edited the code.  Please check if that works

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I think there is a bug in my code.

Comment: @DavidArenburg This will be a nice problem for you.  I am at work now and can hardly concentrate on this.

Comment: @Kevin P, hope the below help.

Comment: 20 8 - eg the last row - should not be present ...

Comment: Why? Yes it should: I want to keep all the elements of idb. So I have to link 8 with someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it my own way, which is kind of slow but works:

```
my_rows = NULL
sets = dt[, .(ida, idb)]
my_rows = sets[!duplicated(idb) & !duplicated(idb, fromLast = TRUE)]
sets = sets[!ida %in% my_rows$ida]

setkey(sets, idb)
for (idb in unique(sets$idb)) {
    elem = sets[J(idb)]
    my_rows = rbind(my_rows, elem[1])
    sets = sets[ida != elem$ida[1]]
}
```

Feel free to post a shorter & faster answer if you have!